# Spring Integration JPA outbound-channel-adapter doing Insert or Update

Tags: spring, jpa, integration

I am new to Spring. I've got to the point successfully passed in an entity to the outbound-channel-adapter and inserted into the database. Right now, my integration looks like:
message-driven-channel-adapter -> transformer -> jpa:outbound-channel-adapter

I need to add business logic to either insert or update depending on a field in the incoming message. It seems like I may need to add a router, gateway and extra jpa:outbound-channel-adapter. Is there a better way?

Comment: Unless you **really** need the flexibility that spring integration provides, it's better to just use a message-driven-channel-adaptor that goes straight to a service activator. There you can have your business logic and later use a DAO/Repository to store the data.

Comment: I am thinking to build a SI template and reuse it many times.

Comment: What you're describing sounds very, very similar to an Abstract class.